# How do I obtain Kernel Density Estimator on a 2D image/array using sklearn?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am working with some images and would like to obtain their KDE using sklearn.
At first I tried an example for a random data that apparently is working just fine:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

# Creating the mock set.
X = np.random.rand(100,100).ravel()[:, np.newaxis]
X_plot = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)[:, np.newaxis]

# Creating the KDEs using different methods.
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.25).fit(X)
log_dens = kde.score_samples(X_plot)
plt.plot(X_plot, np.exp(log_dens))
```

That returns the following:

[image]

Which is not far off what naive me would expect for this random set between 0 and 1. However for my images I obtain a rather weird result:

```
# Listing the data.
imgs = glob('...path/*.npy')

# Loading the image.
test_img = np.load(imgs[0])

X = normalize(test_img.ravel()[:, np.newaxis],axis=0)
X_plot = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)[:, np.newaxis]

# Creating the KDEs using different methods.
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.25).fit(X)
log_dens = kde.score_samples(X_plot)
plt.plot(X_plot, np.exp(log_dens))
```

That returns:

[image]

These images typically have 1000x500 pixels that contain values ranging from -1e18 to 1e18 being about 70% of the values concentrated around |1e13-14| which is why I tried to normalize them but I find it quite weird that the results are going over 1 in the y axis as if I'm not mistaken the very integral of this curve should add to 1.

So why I don't get a reasonable result here? Or am I conceptually wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you just want the plot, then [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) makes this very easy.

Comment: I would also like to obtain the KDE. But I suppose you are talking about a histogram plot? I wasn't aware seaborn could make a KDE analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think maybe you need to use `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` instead of `normalize`.**

When I use your method on 5000 random points from an image (`uint8` hence the shift to 1 I guess), I get:

[image: Result from normalize]

When I standardize using `StandardScaler` on an image, everything else the same apart from `X_plot = np.linspace(-3.1, 3.1, 1000)`, I get:

[image: Result from standarize]

This matches (more or less because of random sampling) the result from `seaborn`, which I trust:

[image: Result from seaborn]

I made that with:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.kdeplot(X, bw=0.1)
```

Sorry, just realized I used a smaller bandwidth than you... but you get the idea.

Comment: Oh nice, that makes much more sense to me and with the histograms I have. I will have a look at them and compare. If I can quickly ask, can I know by how much the pre processing scaled down the numbers?

Comment: @Chicrala The `StandardScalar` subtracts the mean and rescales to unit variance. The new number, `z` is given by `(x - u) / s` where `u` is the mean and `s` is the standard deviation. The trained model has attributes `mean_` and `scale_` with these values.